# A name of a short story where appliances are smart

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have read this in Politikin Zabavnik like more then 25 years ago.
The story was about some smart appliances : toaster witnessing a murder, machine washer caught on cheating husband(not hers of course) and so on...

Comment: The Brave Little Toaster, gone horribly wrong.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is something by Brian Aldiss, but I can't quite recall what.

Answer (score 8):

This is a long shot, but if Politikin Zabavnik ever published any parts of the *Red Dwarf* storyline, written for the TV series of that name, this could be it. The novel *[Better Than Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Than_Life)*, written as a sequel to *Red Dwarf*, had a whole section on biological appliances, GELFs (Genetically Engineered Life Forms) that eventually rebelled against humanity. There is a reference to a man who 'caught his armchair sitting on his naked wife', but nothing about a toaster witnessing a murder, though a toaster is a main character in the rest of the book.

The timeline is about right; the TV episodes aired in the late 80's and the novel came out in 1990-91, so a short story comprising part of the pertinent episodes could have been made as a stand-alone work for a magazine. If this was translated into Serbian, there could well have been some minor plot point differences.

Comment: Doesn't sound like it, but thanks for the answer anyway. I will try to look at Better Than Life deeper and also look for another answer. Thanks again for Your answer.

Comment: No problem. Good luck finding the story; in the meantime, Red Dwarf and Better Than Life are fun reads. Hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

The novel [One of Us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_of_Us_%28novel%29) written by Michael Marshall Smith includes self aware electrical appliances including an alarm clock, fridge and door locks.

The devices can talk and also in some cases move around independently.

The appliances also demonstrate independent thought and even emotions. Examples include a door lock taking a bribe to unlock and let someone in and a kitchen full of appliances worrying about their owners who have been gone for several days.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe satire from Ron Goulart?
[*"What's Become of Screwloose? and Other Inquiries"*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1866977.What_s_Become_of_Screwloose_and_Other_Inquiries) (1971) by Ron Goulart includes the story "Keeping an Eye on Janey," where an electronic bed is actually a private eye that talks like Humphrey Bogart. If not that specific story, perhaps another one of his.

Comment: Yeah, talking appliances made me think of Goulart as well.